# Cambiar formato a una fecha

Tags: java

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando la fecha sea `null` me ponga un espacio en blanco. El problema esta en que la fecha la devuelvo como tipo `Date`, entonces no lo puedo tratar como un `String`

Adjunto lo que tengo

```
if(u.getFechaVigencia() == null){
    u.setFechaVigencia(" ");
}
```

La fecha la recojo directamente de la BBDD con el formato 2019-01-01

Comment: Si es un `Date` solo va a aceptar `Date` o `null`. Si lo que quieres es usar un `String`, para pasar de `Date` a `String` tienes la clase `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 0):

intenta usar el metodo `toString()` sobre la fecha. Es decir `fecha.toString()`. Lo que te hara es devolver una string y ya podras hacer la comparación.
`fecha.toString() == ""` -> vacio, true

Answer (score 0):

Si es un campo `Date` puede tener un `Date` o `null` como dice @JDev.

Si lo que querés es mostrar un espacio (o una cadena vacía) cuando la fecha es `null`, hace eso, cuando lo vayas a imprimir en pantalla, en lugar de formatear la fecha, simplemente imprimes "", pero sin alterar el valor `null` de la variable.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
if(u.getFechaVigencia() == null){
    System.out.println("");
}else{      
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
}
```

Lo mismo cuando uses la variable en otra parte del programa para hacer un cálculo por ejemplo.